# Error when initialize application on other computer

Tags: vb.net, windows, io

Recently i worked on application that's do some backup on specific time.
all goes great and application worked so fine under my computer ( windows 8.1 x64 ).

Now it's time to get the application under some reel test on other machines.

The real problem there is can't run the application at all ( windows 7 x64)

It's show this message :

[image]

and show it's `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`
any help my friends ?

Comment: Can you include the full text of the exception?

Comment: you probably have a file/path hardcoded which does not exist on other's systems.  If it happens right at startup, post the FormLoad event code

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: backup maker.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 54a5bed9
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualBasic

Comment: Problem Signature 05: 10.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba2183b
  Problem Signature 07: 88
  Problem Signature 08: e
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Comment: OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 40d5
  Additional Information 2: 40d5a7fef76887ac5b6e63440762613d
  Additional Information 3: bf5e
  Additional Information 4: bf5eca645b4119c3f7a1c7464c463f82

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: form load : 
        logfie.Text += My.Settings.log
        Label2.Text += My.Settings.time
        clocker.Text = Now.ToString("HH:mm")
        'hour.Hour.ToString("h") & ":" & Now.Minute
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Start()

        ccheck.Interval = 1000
        ccheck.Start()
        Label3.Text = ""

Comment: Looks like it is looking for a file that is not available on the target computer. The file structure from 7 to 8.1 is different.

Comment: OneFineDay - hi friend , i was worked some apps on windows 8.1 and running smoothly on windows 7 :/

Comment: Is your distrubutable just the EXE or do you also have DLLs included? Also, how are you "installing" on the other system? Are you just using a file-copy install or a true installer program?

Comment: exe and dll's , not publish yet just copy past

Comment: You are aware that you can edit the main question, right? I'm referring to the Form Load code. My question is: What is the initial value of My.Settings.log?

Comment: Visual Vincent , initial value could be empty or texts ...

Comment: Oh wait... Haha, I thought so wrong about My.Settings.log. Never mind that anymore. May I now, instead ask what preferences you use?

Comment: Visual Vincent Hi friend i found the problem , it's the devexpress dlls can't register on GAC , when i delete devexpress and all of it components the app work on target computer , but i need to make it work with devexpress template

Answer (score 0):

Since you have depending files (DLLs) and are using a file-copy install method, the problem could be that Windows has blocked the dependent files. When this happens, your program will not be able to access them and will throw the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

To correct it, you need to unblock the files on the problem machine:

1. Right click the DLL library and go to Properties.
2. On the bottom of the General tab, click the Unblock button.
3. Apply the changes.
4. Repeat these steps for all binaries distributed with your program. At the very least, check them all as only some may be blocked.
5. Retry your program.

Comment: there's no Unlock my friend ?

Comment: Hi friend i found the problem , it's the devexpress dlls can't register on GAC , when i delete devexpress and all of it components the app work on target computer , but i need to make it work with devexpress template any help !

Answer (score 0):

If you're not installing the application yet (just copy-pasting), copy the dlls to the [drive letter]:\Windows\System32\ folder, open Command Prompt in Administrator mode and type:

```
regsvr32 [dll file].dll
```

[drive letter] is the letter of the drive where your OS is installed.

[dll file] is the .dll file you want to register.